# How to secure the WEB API from Authenticated users?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

**Overview: What I have done:**

I have created a WEB API & this WEB API has lots of GET & POST methods. I have also implemented JWT Token Authorization so that all the request should be authenticated & authorized.

**Problem Statement:**
Now everything is working fine but what if a user who is an authenticated user of my application changes the `route parameter` value? The request will still be the authenticated request but by doing so, he might access someone else's information.

One way to fix this is, every time the application sends some `Id` parameter, I have to check whether this `Id` belongs to the current user or not? But I think this is a very bad solution.

Does anyone have any suggestion that how can I secure my Web APIs for such cases? I think this is part of the most basic security. So there must be something which I am not aware of. Please help.

Comment: I think you can start this with a table which maps entities and users kinda permission style. Then you can add a custom filter which checks the mapping and authenticating

Comment: Why do you think checking that the Id belongs to a given user is a bad solutions?  How else are you going to ensure that a user only sees their data?

Comment: You clearly has misunderstanding of authentication and authorization. What you have set up so far only finishes authentication, which allows valid users to log in. What you missed is authorization, that for every operation carried out by those users, you validate if that user has the permissions to execute. "One way to fix this" is also a wrong approach. For every incoming request you know who is the user and what operation it tries to do, you should then explicitly verify permissions and decide if that operation can be executed or not. An `Id` field is irrelevant.

Comment: @Fran - I think it as a bad solution because always hitting the database to get some data in order to verify that the data going to be updated belongs to the logged-in user is an extra overload to the server & bad design also.

Comment: @LexLi - I give you an example. Please help me understand how your solution works in that case. I have a ToDoManager application & I want to update the status of my Task (I want to mark it as completed) & every other user using the application can do that. Now, what if I use the postman & keep everything same, just change the Id of the task. In this case, the server has no clue that the task doesn't belong to me. How can I avoid such scenarios? One solution, I think is to use GUID as the primary key. But for integers, I don't know.

Comment: In your database you likely have some objects (records), containing owner data (ID, GUID - does not matter). For accessing and updating data you likely have some stored procedures or similar; you need to use  current user ID as parameter, check against database object owner data, check permissions and perform your action only if permitted. You may cache access rights for heavily used objects - but considering that most operations are allowed  anyway (most users do not change IDs), your database traffic doesn't increase noticeably.